# Guardar ultima url

Tags: php

Entro en **(misitio.com/imagenes)** pero este requiere un Inicio de sesión para acceder hay

Por ende al entrar en **(misitio.com/imagenes)** redireccionara a **(misitio.com/login)**

Si el inicio de sesión es correcto se redireccionara a la ultima url visitada **(misitio.com/imagenes)**

Como se puede hacer este ejemplo en PHP/XAMPP

Este es el codigo que agrego(include) desde otro archivo php a todos los archivos php del sitio para comprobar el inicio de sesion

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['iduser'])){
    header("location: http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/siad/login.php");
}
```

y login.php redirecciona via ajax/js a index.php

```
location.href ="index.php";
```

pero no a la ultima url visitada.

Se que el dilema esta en editar el archivo php que se comunica por vía ajax con login que le envia el url a redireccionar pero no se como hacer para guardar la ultima url del sitio y luego redireccionar si el inicio de sesión es correcto

Comment: Por favor, [edit] tu pregunta y agrega el código que utilizas para realizar la redirección al `login` y el que redirecciona luego de realizar el `login`.

Comment: Esa url la tienes que ir pasando de un script a otro, mejor con get, y la vas capturando hasta que llegues al index.php donde alli, si existe el $_GET correspondiente, haces un location.href acorde con el valor pasado. Por ejemplo: `login?url=/imagenes`, capturandolo con `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` creo que era (y mejor que filtres ese valor, no sea que lo usen los "malos" para redireccionar cosas a traves de tu dominio)